# DualShock 4 suddenly turns off after connecting to iPhone

Tags: ps4, controllers, ios

So, iOS 13 now has support for PS4 and Xbox controllers, and I just bought a DualShock 4 to play Apple Arcade games with it.

I've pressed the Share and the PlayStation button at the same time for 5 seconds, and the controller entered pair mode. It appeared on the list of available Bluetooth devices and I've paired it with my iPhone. But after pairing it, the green light stopped flashing and, a second or two later, an orange light appeared (also for a second or two), and the controller turned off. The bluetooth connection also stoped. Now, when I press the PlayStation button, the controller blinks a green light three times and then turns off.

Am I supposed to pair this controller with a PS4 before being able to use it somewhere else? Is that light scheme trying to communicate some problem with my controller?

EDIT

I thought it could be a bug in iOS, but the same behavior happens when I try to connect it to my iMac.

Comment: iOS 13 is not released yet

Comment: @arghtype A public beta for iOS 13 has been available since june.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works now! I’ve found out that the problem was the controller battery.

For some reason, I cannot charge the DualShock 4 with my phone charger... I’ve tried with an iPhone (and also with an iPad) charger for a couple of hours and the battery was not charge. Then, I connected it to my Mac USB, and an orange light was lit on the controller. I left it charging overnight, and the next morning I was able to successfully connect it via Bluetooth to my iPhone.

So that’s why the controller would quickly disconnect and turn off, because the battery was low.